# Template not displaying anything when add an if/else statement to it

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, zurb-foundation

I am making an ember app and trying to add a log in | sign up to the upper right of the screen if the user is not logged in and a link to their profile | logout button if they are logged in.  However, while I can get one or the other to display, when I add an if statement to the Handlebars template nothing shows up.  Any ideas on why this is happening?

Here is my template:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="medium-2 columns">
            <img src={{"http://placehold.it/200x200"}} alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="medium-2 columns">
        {{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
            <p>{{#link-to 'profile'}}Joe Schmidt{{/link-to}} | <a {{action 'invalidateSession'}}>Logout</a></p>
        {{else}}
            <p>{{#link-to 'login'}}Login{{/link-to}} | {{#link-to 'signup'}}Sign Up{{/link-to}}</p>
        {{/if}}
        </div>
</div>

{{outlet}}
```

Comment: Do you mean that neither "Joe" nor "Login" is displayed?

Comment: Nothing has been being displayed (not even the image or outlet) since I added this if/ else statement. @emberigniter

Comment: That's strange! And no errors whatsoever on the console? Version of Ember...?

Comment: Figured it out! There was some route naming confusion.  @emberigniter

Comment: Voting to close as a typographic error